Application alert pop-up not appearing when browser launched via playwright
self.browser = self.playwright.chromium.launch(
                headless = False,
                slow_mo = 2000,
                devtools= True,
        args = [
            
            r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\chrome_profile",
             "--allow-pre-commit-input" ,
        "--disable-background-networking","--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows","--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled",
        "--disable-browser-side-navigation","--disable-client-side-phishing-detection","--disable-default-apps" ,"--disable-dev-shm-usage","--disable-extensions",
        "--disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor","--disable-gpu","--disable-hang-monitor" ,"--disable-infobars" ,
        "--disable-popup-blocking" ,"--disable-prompt-on-repost","--disable-setuid-sandbox" ,"--disable-software-rasterizer","--disable-sync","--disable-web-security","--enable-automation",
        "--enable-logging ","--ignore-certificate-errors" ,"--log-level=0 "," --no-first-run",
        "--no-sandbox","--no-service-autorun","--password-store=basic","--proxy-bypass-list=*" ,"--proxy-server='direct://'","--remote-debugging-port=0" ,"--test-type" ,
        "--use-mock-keychain","--user-data-"
        ]
        self._browser = BrowserType.create_browser(browser_type)
        self._context = self._browser.new_context(              
                no_viewport = True,
                accept_downloads=True,
                bypass_csp=True,
                ignore_https_errors=True,
                 permissions=["geolocation", "notifications"],
            )
        self._context.clear_cookies()
         self._context.add_cookies([{
         'name': 'name',
         'value': 'value',
         'domain': 'domain',
         'path': '/'
         }])
  
        self._page = self._context.new_page()

<!-- BUTTONS START -->
<br>
&nbsp;
<input type="button" id="rules" name="rules" value="Rules" class="button-raised-primary" onclick="execute(this.form, 'rules');" accesskey="" style="">
&nbsp;
<input type="button" id="marketReport" name="marketReport" value="Launch market report" class="button-raised-primary" onclick="execute(this.form, 'marketReport');" accesskey="" style="">
&nbsp;
<input type="button" id="factReport" name="factReport" value="Launch fact report" class="button-raised-primary" onclick="execute(this.form, 'factReport');" accesskey="" style="">
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
<!-- BUTTONS END -->


This is how i am launching the playwright browser and navigating to pages and when clicked on certain buttons the expected alert pop-up is not coming but if I refresh the browser manually by pausing the execution the pop-up starts appearing on those button click.
Also, we have provided the HTML foe those buttons.
Say when I click to marketReport button, the alert pop-up should appear, but through the playwright browser nothing is happening. Also in the console execute function is not searchable, which if I search through and manually launched browser, it works fine.
Button clicks should throw an alert pop-up every time.
I have tried modifying the args that we pass to the browser during launch, but it didn't work. The alert pop-up should open on clicking buttons without manual intervention.

Please share the site you're automating and a [mcve]. Thanks!

How do you trigger that alert?

Alerts were not visible on screen because by default, dialogs are auto-dismissed by Playwright, so you don't have to handle them. However, you can register a dialog handler before the action that triggers the dialog to either dialog.accept() or dialog.dismiss() it.

Repost of Application pop-up not appearing when browser launched via playwright [closed]
